# Connecting 6awg copper to 2awg aluminum feeder?

Tags: electrical, copper, aluminum-wiring

I want to put a RV 50 amp plug in box about 100 feet from my house.

The 50 amp breaker for the panel won’t accept 2awg aluminum.

I have about 10 feet of 6/6/6/8 copper wire that will work with the breaker.

I’d like to connect that to 2-2-2-4 aluminum underground feeder wire.

Is there a lugged junction box that makes the transition for these wires easy?

Or can the wires be joined safely  in the panel using Polaris type connectors?

Or is there a GE 50 amp breaker that accepts a 2 aluminum wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this thing for EV charging? Stop and talk to us, because going for 50A and a 4-prong socket is a common novice error, danger, waste of money and/or source of trouble... and we can steer you smart.

2-2-2-4 aluminum is a fantastic choice and one of our favorites.  It is 90A wire, and can support *two* RV stands with any mix of receptacles, per NEC 551.73.  The 100' distance is not far enough for voltage drop to be a concern.  Really, even 6-6-6-6 aluminum should be legal, since it is good for 50A.

And you might get lucky and find a socket that takes #2 directly.  No problem finding sockets that take #6 directly (just look for AL-CU and 75C markings).

On the circuit breaker, that's a problem - most manufacturers make their 50A breaker using the same frame/terminal as 15-40A breakers, so they aren't made for #2AL.

Polaris connectors are *very* costly. Your best way to handle this may be to install an "RV subpanel" out at the RV stand. This is a special panel made for RV stands which has a 4-6 space subpanel, and outlets for NEMA 14-50, NEMA TT30, and/or common GFCI outlets.  You can also build this yourself from any random 4-space outdoor panel (e.g. Siemens W0408ML1125U) and an outdoor 14-50 outlet with an in-use cover.   You then use a 60A or 70A breaker at the main panel - these have larger lugs which will happily accept #2.   You can use up to a 90A breaker actually, but 60-70A is cheaper.

If you're GFCI protecting this NEMA 14-50, the GFCI goes out here in this subpanel. It must be the correct brand match for the subpanel.  (e.g. if you bought a HOM GFCI for your HOM main panel, make a point to get a HOM subpanel.)

Comment: It’s a rv.  I misspoke. The aluminum feeder I was going to use is 2awg.

Comment: @Kris OK edited.

Comment: Is it necessary to GFCI protect a stove connected through a NEMA 14-50?

Comment: @Jim that's in flux right now as NEC 2020 and 2023 get adopted and/or states delete that part :) But an RV, that landed on NEC 2020.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I got a NEMA 14-50 receptacle from a big box that said Cu or Al. It does not make as good a connection to the stranded Al conductors of my cable as I would like. It doesn't confine the stranded Al (7 strands per conductor) but splays them out. What is a good brand of NEMA 14-50R for stranded Al conductors? I mail ordered the highly rated Bryant and only when it arrived did I realize it is for Cu only. What connectors should be used for pigtailing with Cu?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica. Is it necessary to place a ground rod out at the rv stand?

Comment: @Jim if it specifies a torque you must set it to that torque.  Make sure any socket is rated AL-CU and 75C if you want to run #6AL at 50A.

Comment: How do I know whether my cable is 6-6-6-6 or 4-4-4-4? Each of the conductors is 7 strands of aluminum with overall diameter 4.8 mm. Each strand is 1/16" (1.6 mm) in diameter.

Comment: @Jim writing on the outside of the cable.  The torque is probably the same for #6 or #4 and both are good for 50A.

Comment: Evidently 7 strands per aluminum conductor is 6 AWG so I have 6-6-6-6.

Comment: Is it appropriate to use one of the crimp sleeves to contain the stranded aluminum cable and prevent the strands from splaying out when the clamping screw in the NEMA 14-50R is tightened?

Comment: @Jim only if the crimp sleeve is listed for aluminum wire. Remember, the terminal was UL-listed to be used in that way.  UL knows the strands are going to get a little crazy, and certified it for that wire size and metallurgy anyway. (assuming that they in fact did).